# Returning non boolean response to jquery validation

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, validation

I am using jquery validation plugin to validate an input form. In the form, when a user enters a value in one field, I do a remote check against a `MySQL` database and if validated, I use the returned value to populate other related fields.

Although the validation method shows a `200` response for `myfield`, because I am returning a `non boolean` string as an `HttpResponse`, the form does not get submitted, but there are no error messages. Once I change the return string to a `"true"`, the form gets submitted!

My question being is a boolean value absolutely needed for the validation to work 
and hence the form to be submitted?

Below if the javascript calling a python method to do a remote check.

```
...
$(#MyForm).validate{
   ...
   rules:{
     myfield:{
       required: true,
       remote : {
        url: "check_field", // method returns non boolean value, values to populate other fields
        type: "post",
        data : {
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken':token,
           this_field: function(){
           return $('#id_myfield').val()
          }, // end of this_field
        }, // end of data
        complete :function (data) {
          console.log("DATA: ", data);
          var str = data.responseText.split(":"); // parse response
          $('#id_other_field1').val(str[0]); // populate other field 1
          $('#id_other_field2').val(str[1]); // populate other field 2

        }, // end of complete
      },// end of remote
    }, // end of myfield
  }, // end of rules
  ...
}// end of form validate
```

The python method called in a django views looks like this

```
def check_field(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        myfield = request.POST.get('myfield')
        # check MySQL database for presence of myfield
        returned_values = some_python_method(myfield)
        if 'absent' in returned_values:
            message = "false"
            return HttpResponse(message)
        else:
            message = returned_values
            return HttpResponse(message, 'application/text')
        ...
```

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. "true" and "false" are just strings, the fact that they look a bit like booleans is completely irrelevant. In any case, nothing in your code appears to depend on the value of those strings.

Comment: Agreed that they are strings. My question then is what is preventing the form from being submitted or what should I change to successfully submit the form?

Comment: That's impossible to answer because you haven't explained what you mean by "preventing the form from being submitted". How is it being "prevented"? What is the symptom of this prevention? What do you actually see? What error do you get?

Comment: I tried `$('#MyForm').on('submit', function(e){ var isvalidate = $("#MyForm").valid(); console.log(isvalidate); }` and it prints `true`. And I don't see any error messages via chrome developer tools. All fields are surrounded by green and clicking submit does nothing, the page is static with all field values.

Comment: I meant to type green border around fields indicating that those fields were validated.